# OneToOne mapping causes parent to be saved twice

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

In my Spring Boot + Hibernate (5.5.7.Final) project, I have a parent object with a OneToOne relation to a child, and two business ids:

```java
@Id private long id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
   fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
Child child;

@Column String idA;
@Column String idB;
```

The child has the following mapping to the parent:

```java
@OneToOne
@MapsId
private Parent parent
```

There is a unique index on idA and idB in the database.

When running this I see a lot of duplicate entry errors in my DB, on the unique index. For some reason, hibernate attempts to insert `Parent` twice. It is somehow caused by the child, because when I replace the JPA mapping on `Child` with an `@Transient`, the problem is gone.

What can cause this?

Comment: Do you have any query/update reordering enabled? Which version of Hibernate are you using? How are you saving the parent and child? Can you post the SQL queries that Hibernate produces for a single save where this happens? This might provide a hint of what Hibernate is trying to do, especially if you also post the parameters for those queries.

Comment: Hibernate 5.5.7.Final
The class I called parent here, is actually in a cascade.ALL @OneToMany with another class, and we call a Spring data repository .save() on that class.
About query reordering, it's not set, we use whatever the default is.

I'll see about the queries, but it does not happen always, so those might be hard to grab. This is also a production system, so I cannot post any real queries or values

Comment: @JessevanBekkum, try removing `@OneToOne` mapping from Child entity

Comment: If this doesn't happen all the time you should watch for patterns of when this happens, e.g. in a certain process or maybe a combination of actions. Then try to reproduce it in a dev or test environment. If you can only get the queries from production, try to obfuscate values - important are ids, condition parameters and version parameters (if you're using those). Also note that `idA` and `idB` might be duplicated by 2 distinct parent entities so the actual problem might not be related to Hibernate or at least only be partially related.

Comment: I more or less debugged it. We saved twice, and spring would execute an insert both times, causing this issue. By replacing the first one with saveAndFlush, it properly did an insert the first time and an update the second time.

Somehow, if Child is @Transient, hibernate doesn't do an insert on the second call, but an update. I can't explain that part